# Where is the /proc folder on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, proc

I am reading a book that speaks about Bash in Linux systems. But I am a Mac OS X user and I cant find `/proc` folder in my machine.

Where I can see the Mac OS X terminal equivalent of the `/proc` folder?

Comment: read "Mac OS X internals" by Amit Singh (ISBN 0321278542 http://osxbook.com/ ) for more on the way Mac OS X specifically does things. A more generic intro to Unix: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/unix_course/ with a nice+small chapter on shells: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/unix_course/intro-55.html

Comment: Update for 2020: See Jonathan Levin's *Mac OS and \*OS Internals* at [newosxbook.com](http://newosxbook.com/).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To communicate with the kernel, different UNIX systems use different interfaces - not necessarily [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs). It's not a must-have. While it's become quite common with Linux and FreeBSD indeed, OS X (which is based on BSD) does not implement a procfs.

The equivalents to most proc calls would be found in other tools such as `sysctl(8)` and the `sysctl(3)` call. Read the manpages (`man 8 sysctl` or `man 3 sysctl`) for some examples. Other things you can do with proc cannot be done easily on OS X. This is just a design choice.

See also:

- [/proc on Mac OS X](http://web.archive.org/web/20200103161748/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/procfs/)
- [A MacFUSE-Based Process File System for Mac OS X](http://web.archive.org/web/20200513034043/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/)

Note that Bash is just a shell (a command line program) that you can use within a terminal emulator (such as *Terminal.app* on OS X). The shell does not have anything to do with the underlying file system or system architecture. You could switch to any other shell like Zsh or csh – or even another terminal emulator such as [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) – and still use the procfs.

Comment: Excellent `procfs` article you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the online man pages form Apple were archived and these links to sysctl(3) and sysctl(8) are broken now.
I could find a mirror only to [sysctl.3](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) only in a mirror website.

I would recommend to use the built in man pages in the OS as a source of truth using `$man sysctl`

Comment: I don't seem to have a man page for sysctl on Mojave. I miss proc.

Comment: @Kallaste I'm not on Mojave yet, so I can't test it, but manpages might only be available with Xcode command line tools. On High Sierra, `man sysctl` still works.

Comment: `man sysctl` works on OSX Catalina

Comment: `man sysctl` works on macOS Sonama