# Why does htop on Mac OS X require root privileges to see data for all processes, but on Linux it runs without root

Tags: linux, macos, mac, sudo, htop

I use `htop` all the time when I'm working on Linux system. I've installed `htop-osx` through Homebrew on my Mac, but in order to see all data for all processes, [the formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/htop.rb#L41-L47) tells me that I need to run `htop` as root, using `sudo`.

On a Linux system, it appears that root privileges are not required to show all data for all processes in `htop`.

My question is *why* do I need to do this on a Mac, but I don't on a Linux system?

Previously, the suggested solution to this problem was to set the `setuid` bit on the `htop` binary and `chown` the binary to root so that it runs as the root user. However, [a change](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/299f8a27d17ce93c2c7dd8bb5719cd6a3152305e#diff-f2c362f0cb7316d896279dd18daa4dbd) was made away from this method to use `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Linux, htop uses the /proc filesystem, which allows viewing information provided by the kernel.  That (/proc) is not part of OSX, so (like some other systems lacking this feature), one can only get at the kernel's data using privileged access.

For more discussion

- [Where is the /proc folder on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/631693/where-is-the-proc-folder-on-mac-os-x) (2013)
- [Where did the /proc directory go in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72619/where-did-the-proc-directory-go-in-mountain-lion) (2012)
- [A MacFUSE-Based Process File System for Mac OS X](https://web.archive.org/web/20200816070829/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/) (2007)
- [/proc on Mac OS X](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161748/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/procfs/) (2003)