# How to automatically rename tmux window to an aliased command

Tags: zsh, tmux, alias

I have set up multiple aliases to ssh to different servers

```
alias sa="ssh user1@server1"
alias sb="ssh user2@server2"
alias sc="ssh user3@server3"
```

When I run these commands from tmux, all windows are renamed to `ssh`, instead of `sa`,`sb`,`sc`. How do I get the alias to show up as the window name instead of the actual process name?

Edit: Using macOS 12.2.1, tmux 3.2a, zsh 5.8

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: So, do you believe that the OP can solve their program by replacing `sa`, `sb` and `sc` with scripts? Or C programs (that call ``system("ssh …")`` )?

Comment: I guess a program (binary executable) named `sa` will solve the problem. A script (text file with a shebang) may not though (e.g. in my Kubuntu an executable script interpreted by `bash` is still seen by `tmux` as `bash`; I don't know macOS at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preliminary notes

- Some parts of the analysis (below) apply mainly to Linux.
- The solution had been tested in Kubuntu 21.10 and published. Only then the OP revealed they are using macOS; it turned out the solution does not work in macOS.
- I decided not to delete the answer (yet), but please be advised it may or may not work in a non-Linux OS.

---

#### tl;dr

```
alias sa='bash -c '\''exec -a "$0" ssh user1@server1 "$@"'\'' sa'
```

Or [better(?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618) (`unalias sa` first, if needed):

```sh
sa() {
   bash -c 'exec -a "$0" ssh user1@server1 "$@"' sa "$@"
}
```

---

#### Analysis – what you can do in `tmux`

`tmux` by default changes the name of the window according to the executable being run in the active pane. This is governed by the [`automatic-rename` option](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#automatic-rename):

> `automatic-rename [on | off]`
> Control automatic window renaming. When this setting is enabled, `tmux` will rename the window automatically using the format specified by `automatic-rename-format`. This flag is automatically disabled for an individual window when a name is specified at creation with `new-window` or `new-session`, or later with `rename-window`, or with a terminal escape sequence. […]

I assume you want this setting to stay enabled.

You could rename the window on demand (`tmux rename-window sa`) and re-enable the setting (`tmux set-option -w automatic-rename on`) before or after calling `ssh`. But:

- if before `ssh`, then selecting another pane in the same window will make `automatic-rename` do its job (you probably expect this), but selecting back the pane with `ssh` will rename the window to `ssh`, not `sa`;
- if after `ssh`, then selecting another pane in the same window (before `ssh` finishes) won't rename the window.

There may be other disadvantages; neither method is perfect. Also note if you play with `set-option -w automatic-rename` in more than one pane then commands in one pane may configure the `tmux` window differently than the other pane tries to impose. Changing the setting back and forth is not a good solution.

A good solution will make `tmux` set `sa` as the title automatically. We need a way to tell `tmux` to use the string `sa` instead of `ssh`. For this we need to learn how `tmux` knows it's `ssh` you're running.

---

#### Analysis – what `tmux` knows

`tmux` provides a terminal for your shell. When the shell spawns `ssh`, the shell puts itself in the background by making the process group of the `ssh` the foreground process group. When `ssh` exits, the shell as the parent process reacts, it puts itself in the foreground by setting its process group as the foreground one. The main purpose of this "juggling" is to make job control work (background processes with stdin still connected to the terminal, in case you `fg` them; but unable to "steal" input until their process group becomes the foreground process group).

The ability of `tmux` (or another process) to know the name of the foreground executable is only a useful side effect of this mechanism. Knowing the foreground process group for the terminal it provides, `tmux` can find the process being the group leader and adjust the title automatically.

The shell does nothing to directly inform `tmux` what command is being executed. If this was the case, a smart enough shell could pass `sa` instead of `ssh`. Your shell decides what process group (and when) becomes the foreground process group associated with the terminal (in `tmux` context: the pane). By monitoring this, `tmux` can find the foreground process(es) in the pane.

An alias is not a process. Each of your aliases runs an executable named `ssh`. `tmux` has no means to know the alias you used. That's why your windows were renamed to `ssh`, no matter which alias you used.

---

#### Solution

It turns out it's not the name of the foreground executable that really matters to `tmux`. What matters is the string you can see as the first (some would say "zeroth") null-terminated entry in `/proc/PID/cmdline`. Usually (by convention) it's the path to the executable or its name; but it can be virtually anything.

There are ways to run `ssh` (or whatever) and specify a custom string. See [*Setting the thread `/proc/PID/cmdline`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139859/10765659). In Bash `exec -a …` can do this. But don't invoke it directly from your interactive shell, because `exec` will *replace* the shell with whatever you want to run. Thus you need an extra `bash` that will be replaced. Example:

```
bash -c 'exec -a "foo" sleep 300'
```

The above command invoked in a shell inside `tmux` will make `tmux` rename the window to `foo` (if `automatic-rename` is `on`; and you may need to wait few seconds).

A basic alias that uses this approach is:

```
alias sa='bash -c "exec -a sa ssh user1@server1"'
```

I notice your aliases work well with additional arguments. I mean e.g. your `sa sleep 30` expands to `ssh user1@server1 sleep 30` which is a sane command that runs `sleep 30` on the server. Our alias does not support this yet. This is the fix:

```
alias sa='bash -c '\''exec -a sa ssh user1@server1 "$@"'\'' whatever'
```

where `whatever` is like the second `sh` in [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690) Personally I prefer passing the desired name instead of `whatever`:

```
alias sa='bash -c '\''exec -a sa ssh user1@server1 "$@"'\'' sa'
```

Or maybe (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
alias sa='bash -c '\''exec -a "$0" ssh user1@server1 "$@"'\'' sa'
```

Note `sa` near the end does not need to match the name of the alias. Here it matches because you want this.

The alias is somewhat complicated. It works, nevertheless [it's beyond what aliases are for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618). An equivalent function may be considered more elegant. This is the function (`unalias sa` first, if needed):

```sh
sa() {
   bash -c 'exec -a "$0" ssh user1@server1 "$@"' sa "$@"
}
```

---

#### Notes

- `exec -a` is not portable, it works in Bash, it doesn't work in pure `sh`. Still the alias itself (or the function itself) is valid in any POSIX-like shell. It calls `bash` explicitly, no matter what your main shell is.
- There are other tools that read `/proc/PID/cmdline` or equivalent information. Our solution may mislead them or users using them. E.g. `ps -eo pid,comm,command` will print `ssh` in the `comm` column, but `sa` in the `command` column.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive analysis. I tried the solution you suggested - both using alias and the function. However I am seeing the same results, that is the window still gets renamed to ssh and not the alias/function name.

One thing I missed to mention in the original question, is that I am using zsh, not bash, as my default shell. Not sure if the shell choice between bash and zsh would make any difference though.

Comment: @AbhijeetViswam Cannot replicate. The solution works for me in Bash and in Zsh. My `tmux -V` returns `tmux 3.1c`. My `bash --version` shows `5.1.8`.

Comment: @AbhijeetViswam For now I cannot tell why the solution doesn't work for you. In case your Bash is old (buggy?) and your Zsh is new, try replacing `bash -c` with `zsh -c`. AFAIK `exec -a` works in Zsh. Or it can be your `tmux` does things differently for some reason. Please edit the question and state your OS and its version; and the version of tmux. There are differences between Linux, macOS, another Unix-like OS, WSL, Cygwin, … ([example](https://superuser.com/a/631696/432690)) and maybe your `tmux` sees the real name despite our efforts. My tests were in Linux (Kubuntu 21.10).

Comment: @ KamilMaciorowski You are probably right about the OS dependency. I tried it on an Ubuntu VM with the same tmux version and your solution worked fine.